# Adding 3rd party jQuery code to our Rails RTF text box

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I am adding a 3rd party feature into an existing rails app. The 3rd party gave me a piece of code which I am supposed to drop into my codebase but I'm confused as to where this should be posted.

Posted is the 3rd party which I am supposed to add to my codebase:

```
<script src="http://serviceweareusing.com/js/version-latest?cid=ourcompany"></script>
<script>
$("#textbox").featureBox('init',{rte:true,userid:'<ENTER CURRENT USERNAME>'});
</script>
```

Posted is the existing code in my app for the form.

**_post_form.html.erb**

```
<div class="create-post-row">
    <label>Body</label>                     
    <textarea id="textbox">
        <%= @post.body %>
    </textarea>
    <%= form.hidden_field :body, :id => 'body_hidden_input' %>
    <%= errors_for_field :body %>
</div>
```

Where should this be posted? Does it go in a separate .js file or can I paste it right into the embedded ruby? Any insight would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a .js file in your /app/assets/javascripts folder.

make sure your "application.js" file has **//= require_tree .** at the end.